# Unable to read excel file on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to read Excel sheet in my asp.net web-site.
File is uploaded by user and then I read it and show result in Grid View. 
Every things works fine when I run it in Visual Studio Environment. 
But when I tried same code on IIS it giving an Exception `Unspecified Error`. 
I am using following code:

```
string excelConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+Server.MapPath("~/doc/")+ filepath+";Extended Properties="+ "\"" + "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;" + "\"";
        string query = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        con.Open();               // Exceptionoccurs here
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        testGrid.DataSource = dt;
        testGrid.DataBind();
```

Exception Stack Trace:

```
[OleDbException (0x80004005): Unspecified error]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +351
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +86
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +76
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +43
   DataBaseSolution.DbSolution.select(String connection, String providername, String query) in F:\vs backup\DataBaseSolution\DataBaseSolution\DbSolution.cs:63
   _Default.insertDb(String filepath) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\Default.aspx.cs:82
   _Default.checkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\Default.aspx.cs:39
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Please suggest me any update in code or any other method by which I can do this task.

**Edited: Provided Stack Trace and marked line with a comment where Exception Occurs**

Comment: You should enclose the the OleDbConnection and OleDbDataReader in using block as they implement IDisposable (via their interfaces/base class) and then you don't have to manually close them.

Answer (score 6):

check permissions -> security 
or 
check your Application Pool -> Advanced Setting -> enable 32 Applications -> True

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have a MS. Oledb driver installed and then try this code

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
OleDbDataReader dr;
connection.Open();
dr = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

//dbo.Employees
cn.Open();

dt.Load(dr);
cn.Close();
```

Comment: You should enclose the the OleDbConnection and OleDbDataReader in using block as they implement IDisposable (via their interfaces/base class) and then you don't have to manually close them.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with the OleDb-provider for Excel a few times and if you ask me it's really horrible. In my last project where I needed to work with Excel-files I went with http://epplus.codeplex.com/ which is a managed library which wins in both speed and easiness to use compared to the OleDb-variant. The drawback is that it only supports .xslx-files (not .xsl) but if you can live without that then it is a much better way to do it.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience, cna we use ODBC connection because when i try the same using ODBC driver connection it also causes issue on IIS

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well it's really hard to include more then the name and an explanation of the library in the question. At best I could have added a sample as well though without the library (which I can't include in the answer) the sample would be useless.

Comment: The 3-vote answer `check permissions -> security or check your Application Pool -> Advanced Setting -> enable 32 Applications -> True` answers the question. You have suggested using a 3rd party library. It is really not even an answer. Not sure why a 2.5 year old answer came up in my queue but I stand by my review.